# How can I test if Tomcat has SSL support enabled?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a problem: I'm configuring a Tomcat server to serve a webservice through HTTPS, and it isn't working.

If I go to the 38080 port, the service is working perfectly, but if I go to the 8443 port (using the https prefix), the browser shows me an error message (The page can't be shown).

The server is a Windows 2008 R2, Tomcat is 6.0.35 and Java is 1.6.0_29.

The SSL content of the `server.xml` file is:

```
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keyAlias="server" 
           keystoreFile="${catalina.base}\conf\test-keystore.jks" 
           keypass="patata"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

The file `test-keystore.jks` is a self-generated keystore, based on the documentation at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html. The order used was: `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore test-keystore.jks`.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, and how to solve this problem?

**MORE INFORMATION**
The logs doesn't show any error. Neither stdout or the ${catalina.base}/logs/manager-{date}.log or the ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost-{date}.log

Comment: what has this got to do with Java?

Comment: @ScaryWombat maybe Tomcat is a java based server, for running web java applications?

Comment: Yes, but the question does not have any Java component.

Comment: @Kayaman It's a good idea, but the logs doesn't show any error... And I've changed the loglevel to FINE :/

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED!**

The problem was with the configuration. The `keyAlias` parameter is incorrect, it should be `keyAlias="tomcat"` and not `keyAlias="server"`.